# how can I debug(set breakpoint) the native source code of cordova-ios in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

for make a good knowledge of the cordova (ios), I think I should read and debug the native source code step by step.

however, I'm new to ios. and be unfamiliar with XCode 4.3.

I have install the cordova-1.6.1, and also build the cordova project.
so how can I link the source code with all the .m files, I want set a breakpoint in the .m file.

For example, I want set a breakpoint in the CDVPlugin.m for debugging the process of instaning the plugin .

thanks for giving me a guide.